# Index mechanism used in GRIDDB

Tags: distributed-computing, database-indexes, griddb

Griddb uses a hybrid indexing system that combines hash indexes and tree-based indexes. What advantages does it offer over a pure hash or tree-based approach? Is it similar to [Adaptive Hybrid Index](https://db.in.tum.de/%7Eanneser/ahi.pdf?lang=en) ?